Edit dialog: "Save without review" is unclear, add a standard "save edits" button
A staging ground question has an outstanding major issue, but it also has a minor formatting issue that I can fix. I click edit, fix the formatting, and try to click the submit button, which is not in the normal position.
Eventually, I find the "review question" info box, which clarifies things:

Save without review:
Save your edits to the question without leaving a review. It’s highly encouraged to also leave a review.

I think a nicer form of this UI, in line with the existing "review queue" functionality, would be to have a "Save Edits" button in the usual place. If you click it, it functions the exact same as the "Save without review" option: it returns you to the staging ground view where you can choose what to do next.

Note that if you have unsent comments, these may disappear (relevant beta post)
